# Print в одну строку

Tags: python

Как объеденить строки print?

```
print(*[((alph.index(i)+1)**5 % 91) for i in a]) 
print(*[(alph.index(i)+1) for i in a])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
print(*[ [((alph.index(i)+1)**5 % 91), (alph.index(i)+1)] for i in a ])
```

Comment: Почему мне кажется, что тут порядок не тот будет?

Answer (score 2):

способ 1:

```
print(*[((alph.index(i)+1)**5 % 91) for i in a], end='') 
print(*[(alph.index(i)+1) for i in a])
```

способ 2:

```
print(*[((alph.index(i)+1)**5 % 91) for i in a], *[(alph.index(i)+1) for i in a])
```

способ 3:

```
print(*([((alph.index(i)+1)**5 % 91) for i in a] + [(alph.index(i)+1) for i in a]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, как-то так должно сработать:

```
ind = [alph.index(i)+1 for i in a]
print(*(x**5 % 91 for x in ind), *ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> print(*[((alph.index(i)+1)**5 % 91) for i in a] end="") 
> print(*[(alph.index(i)+1) for i in a])
> ```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]